# google map location balloon displays latitude and longitude instead of its address

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<a  class="location_map" onclick='javascript:window.open("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=10.804404555920602,78.72114462280274&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed","_blank","toolbar=yes,width=800,height=500,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=250,left=200");' id="mal1">Click To View Map</a><br>
```

hello friends i am having above line of code and its display latitude and longitude values in address balloon.

 but the below code show it fine in balloon but not exact shows latitude,longitude position on map.. 
`<a  class="location_map" onclick='javascript:window.open("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Periyar+Nagar+1st+Street,+Malayappa+Nagar,+Tiruchirappalli,+Tamil+Nadu+620004,+India&amp;aq=&amp;sll=10.804404555920602,78.72116608047486&amp;sspn=0.012057,0.021136&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Periyar+Nagar+1st+Street,+Malayappa+Nagar,+Tiruchirappalli,+Tamil+Nadu+620004,+India&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=&amp;output=embed","_blank","toolbar=yes,width=800,height=500,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,top=250,left=200");' id="mal1">Click To View Map</a>`
 and my need is to display the correct position which is marked by user before,with right address on balloon..

Answer (score 0):

Place this in Head section of your HTML

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.479084, -97.823937),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And this in Body Section - div id="map_canvas"

This will show the map with the values of latitude and longitude you provide as the center of the map.